# Why it is able to split between 82 and 10?

Tags: algorithm, merge, mergesort

If I have the array [9, 82, 10]. By using the merge sort, I should compare the left index to the right index and if l < r, I split it to two arrays, right? But in the video, it shows that it has been cut it to half between 82 and 10. But, 82 > 10. I am so confused.

Comment: In what video you have seen it?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JSceec-wEyw

Answer (score 3):

I think you confuse this logic with maybe another algorithm (QuickSort maybe?), because the split happens *irrespective* of the values. Where the split happens is only influenced by the current length of the array. The idea is to split the array in *half*. In case the length of the array is odd, that is not exactly possible, so the middle element is then put  in the left or right part (it does not matter).

In this case it could split the array in either `[9]` and [`82, 10`] or in `[9, 82]` and `[10]`. Apparently you have seen it happen like in the latter case.

Only *after* the split the actual values start to play a role. This is when the parts are merged back together. First the left and right part are sorted (recursively), and then the left and right part are merged.

During that merge, a value from the left part and a value from the right part are compared. Every time the smaller one is put in the result array, and the "pointer" of where it came from is moved one position ahead.

In short: merge sort has two phases: split and merge. Values are not compared during the split phase, only during the merge phase.

Comment: Oh, so it dose not matter where I split in an odd array. That make sense, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

To further clarify, no sorting or merging takes place until recursion produces two sub-arrays of size 1, at which point merging begins, and then follows the stack path, merging in a depth first / left first pattern (the animation makes this appear to be in parallel).

The particular implementation used in the video works with first and last indexes. The middle index effectively is (first+last)/2, and since array[4] = 9, array[5] = 82, array[6] = 10, first = 4, last = 6, middle = (4+6)/2 = 5, so it splits the sub-array into array[4,5] and array[6,6]. Although this is common for quick sort, most merge sorts work with beginning and ending index, beginning index = first index, and ending index = 1 + last index. In this case, begin = 4, end = 7, middle = (4+7)/2 = 5, and the split would be array[4, 5) = array[4,4] and array[5,7} = array[5,6] (using ...} to indicate the ending index = 1 + last index).

It should also be noted that most library implementations of stable sorts are some variation of iterative bottom up merge sort, which skips the recursive process and instead considers an array of n elements as n sorted runs of size 1, and begins merging immediately, in breadth first (across the array) order, merging even and odd runs, which doubles the size of sorted runs until run size >= array size. Typical variations of merge sort are hybrids of insertion sort and merge sort, such as timsort.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort